# Plotting a graph and contour in the same canvas in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, contour

I want to plot a graph and on the top of it a contour. And then obtain the points where the contour lines intersect with graph line. I am trying something like this

```
plt.hold(True)
plt.contour(X, Y, Z)
plt.plot(tp,cp)
```

But I couldn't plot them. Please help me in getting the plots done.

Comment: Can you provide the code snippet and graphs image at least?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding intersection between straight line and contour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232311/finding-intersection-between-straight-line-and-contour)

Comment: I could plot it now.plt.hold(True)
plt.contour(A, B, Z,colors='blue',linestyles='dashed')
plt.contour(A, B, D,colors='red',linestyles='dashed')
plt.plot(fpr,tpr)